# How remove all records with queryRunner.manager.remove?

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm, query-builder

I have a Nest.JS and TypeORM code that deletes multiple rows and then inserts multiple rows.

```
async bulkUpdate(
    where: any = {},
    something: SomethingDto[],
    connection: Connection,
  ) {
    const queryRunner = connection.createQueryRunner();
    await queryRunner.connect();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();

    try {
      // delete all
      await queryRunner.manager.remove(something,{chunk: 1000});

      // create new ones
      await queryRunner.manager.save(something, { chunk: 1000 });

      return await queryRunner.commitTransaction();
    } catch (error) {
      if (queryRunner.isTransactionActive) {
        await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();

        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    }
  }
```

I cannot figure out how to remove all records from the table for concrete userId.

Comment: Did you tried saving it using `save()` refer: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3518

Comment: Yes, but the save method does not allow to use commitTransaction method, which will be sure that delete and after the insert is done correctly. I mean I need to be sure that delete and insert all are finished, and then go further.

Comment: One thing I would suggest is to enable logs and check the queries. https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3518#issuecomment-457819055 This comment states that even with chunk option the typeorm generates single insert query for a single record. So, I guess it won't be useful if that is the behavior.